# Proof of inequality of sums

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

I have the following to prove, with induction and any help would be appreciated! :)

$n\in \mathbb{N}, \quad \left(\, x^{1},\ldots,x^{n}\,\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$

$$
\left(\,\sum^{n}_{i\ =\ 1}x^{i}\,\right)^{2}\leq
n\sum^{n}_{i\ =\ 1}\left(\, x^{i}\,\right)^{2}
$$

Thank you!

Comment: i would try induction for $n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{{\bf v} \equiv \pars{x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}}\quad\mbox{and}\quad{\bf u}\equiv\pars{\overbrace{1,\ldots,1}^{\ds{\color{#c00000}{n}\ \mbox{times}}}}}$

\begin{align}
&\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n}x_{i}={\bf v}\cdot{\bf u} \leq \verts{\bf v}\verts{\bf u}
=\root{\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}}\root{\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n}1^{2}}
=\root{\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}}\root{n}
\\[5mm]&\imp\ 
\color{#66f}{\large%
\pars{\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n}x_{i}}^{2}\leq n\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $${\left( {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{a_i}{b_i}} } \right)^2} \leqslant \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{{\left( {{a_i}} \right)}^2}} .\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{{\left( {{b_i}} \right)}^2}},$$
with $a_i=1$, $b_i=x^i$, we get the result.